# Google Chrome not showing emoticon

Tags: google-chrome, icons

When I open this [website](http://www.symbols-n-emoticons.com/p/facebook-emoticons-list.html) using Google Chrome, I am not able to see some of the icons. See the screenshot below:
[image: Chrome]

As you can see, some of the icons appears as a box.

But everything is ok when I open using IE/Firefox, even though they appear slightly different. Here is how it looks on IE:
[image: IE]

And here is how it looks on FF:
[image: FF]

My browsers' version are as follows:

```
Chrome : 40.0.2214.115 m
IE : 11.0.9600.17631
FF : 36.0
```

What caused this and how to solve it?

Comment: Have you cleared your cache? Or tried incognito?

Comment: Yes, tried both, but it still the same